# Sumar al interior de una declaración ¿Por qué compila?

Tags: c++

El otro día vi el siguiente código:

```
int main()
{
    int *p; int tam;
    cout << "Ingrese el tamaño" << endl;
    cin >> tam;
    p = new int[tam + 5];
    p[0] = 67;
    p[1] = 72;
    p[2] = 15;
    p[3] = 81;
    p[4] = 23;
    cout << *(p+2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Y ante la pregunta:

> "¿Qué es lo que sucede con este programa?"

Yo pensé que no compilaría porque  `p = new int[tam + 5]` no es una expresión válida. Especialmente por `int[tam + 5]`.

Sin embargo, estaba equivocado. El programa compila y lo que hace es mostrar por consola el 15.

> Yo respondí: No compila. Lo que es incorrecto

Y ahora, si bien entiendo porque muestra el 15 no encuentro documentación o cosas para leer sobre expresiones al estilo `int[tam + 5]`. ¿Qué es lo que sucede en el compilador?

Por otro lado, ¿Cuál es la utilidad de dichas expresiones?¿Se usan realmente?

PD: Creo que tendría que cambiar el título a algo más representativo. ¿Esto está dentro de aritmética de apuntadores?

Comment: Como puedes ver en [este enlace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) `new int[tam + 5]` es equivalente al operador `calloc(tam + 5, sizeof(int))`. El equivalente al `free(..)` sería el operador `delete`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En [este enlace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) podrás comprobar que en C++ el operador `new int[tam + 5]` es equivalente a la llamada en C `calloc(tam + 5, sizeof(int))`. Ambos reservan memoria para `tam + 5` elementos de tipo `int`. El equivalente a la llamada `free(..)` sería el operador `delete []`.

Aunque el funcionamiento es equivalente y se pueden usar las funciones `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `free()`, etc en C++, no se recomienda mezclar ambos métodos porque cada uno tiene su propio juego de funciones y operadores.

**¿Cuál es la utilidad de dichas expresiones? ¿Se usan realmente?**

Por supuesto, es la práctica más habitual para crear conjuntos de datos dinámicos (vectores, matrices, etc) de datos primitivos (como `int`, `float`, etc).

**¿Esto está dentro de aritmética de apuntadores?**

Al fin y al cabo son punteros, por lo que es equivalente, aunque el término "aritmética de apuntadores" es un tanto confuso.

**¿Qué es lo que sucede en el compilador?**

Trataré de explicarlo en comentarios:

```
int main()
{
    int *p; int tam;
    cout << "Ingrese el tamaño" << endl;
    /* Guardamos el entero que introduzcan en la variable "tam" */
    cin >> tam;
    /* Creamos una matriz unidimensional (vector) de (tam + 5) elementos */
    p = new int[tam + 5];
    /* Ninguno genera error a menos que "tam" sea negativo, en cuyo caso
      podríamos provocar un volcado de pila por violación de segmento */
    p[0] = 67;
    p[1] = 72;
    p[2] = 15;
    p[3] = 81;
    p[4] = 23;
    /* "p" apunta al elemento 0, por lo que p + 2 incrementa el puntero
      2 posiciones de tamaño "int", accediendo al elemento 0 + 2 = 2 (15) */
    cout << *(p+2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Trauma, creo recordar que eso sólo ocurre en C, en C++ se puede usar una expresión no constante.

Comment: @Trauma no entiendo, `tam` no es una expresión constante y no veo porque sería error.

Comment: @Xam Precisamente por eso: porque es una variable.En otras palabras: lo que pongamos **dentro de los corchetes** ha de ser conocido por el compilador en tiempo de compilación.

Comment: @Trauma pero en el código se crea un vector dinámico, no uno estático. De ahí que no veo error. Otra cosa sería hacer: `cout << "Ingrese el tamaño" << endl; cin >> tam; p[tam+5]`, sin usar el operador `new`, lo cual si estaría mal (a pesar de como bien señalas, algunos compiladores lo permiten)

Comment: Estoy contigo @Xam.

Comment: ¡¡ Ostia !! ¡¡ LLevais razón los 2 !! ¡¡ que es dinámico !! No se como lo he mirado, pero no he visto el `new` O_O

Comment: @Trauma ya estabas empezando a confundirme xD.

Comment: @OscarGarcia solo un pequeño apunte: me parece que en el código se crea un vector y no una matriz.

Comment: @Xam técnicamente un vector consta de un origen, una dirección y sentido, aunque también se usa ese término para definir matrices de una única fila e incluso coordenadas de un punto de N dimensiones.

Comment: Aún así si piensas que el término "vector" está más ampliamente aceptado que "matriz" puedes sugerir o hacer una edición para que quede constancia de tu aporte. Por mi parte no hay problema.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ok, entendido.

Comment: Aquí más información, por si te es de interés: [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(informática)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29) donde puedes leer: "En programación se denomina matriz, vector (de una sola dimensión) o formación (en inglés array)", por lo que la confusión es máxima xD

Answer (score 2):

> Yo pensé que no compilaría porque `p = new int[tam + 5]` no es una expresión válida.

En C++ hay dos formas de llamar a `new`:

- Reservas simples (un único elemento)

  ```
  int* ptr = new int;
  MiClase* obj = new MiClase(param1,param2);
  ```
- Reservas de arrays (múltiples elementos)

  ```
  int* ptr = new int[5]; // array de 5 elementos de tipo int
  MiClase** lista = new MiClase*[10]; // array de 10 elementos de tipo MiClase*
  ```

Por otro lado, fíjate que dentro de los corchetes se indica el número de elementos que va a contener el array (dato necesario para que el sistema sepa cuántos bytes de memoria necesita). Este tamaño puede ser un valor prefijado en tiempo de compilación:

```
int* ptr = new int[5];
```

Pero también puede ser un valor proporcionado en tiempo de ejecución:

```
int size;
std::cin >> size;
int* ptr = new int[size];
```

Debido a esta segunda característica, el tamaño debe poder evaluarse en tiempo de compilación y por este motivo no hay inconveniente en que el tamaño venga dado por una ecuación:

```
int size;
std::cin >> size;
int* ptr = new int[size + 10];
int* ptr2 = new int[size + sin(size) * abs(size-20)];
```

Lo que sucede en estos casos es que se evaluará en primer lugar la expresión que indica el número de elementos y, posteriormente, se ejecutará una llamada a la función `new` con el fin de reservar la memoria necesaria.

Luego, como puedes ver, la expresión que comentas es totalmente válida.

> ¿Qué es lo que sucede en el compilador?

No sucede nada del otro mundo. El compilador se encuentra con una llamada para reservar un array de elementos y, simplemente, realiza dicha llamada.

> ¿Cuál es la utilidad de dichas expresiones?

Esa llamada sirve para reservar arrays para un número indeterminado de elementos. Ni más ni menos.

> ¿Se usan realmente?

Lo cierto es que sí.

La reserva de memoria dinámica es un proceso bastante lento ya que implica una serie de operaciones que pueden ser bastante pesadas.

Si sabes que vas a tener que gestionar una colección de `x` elementos es mucho más rápido solicitar una única reseva para almacenar esos elementos que hacer `x` reservas individuales... además que con esta práctica la memoria sufrirá menos fragmentación y eso hará que la máquina se ralentice aun menos (y eventualmente que se quede sin memoria pese a tener memoria libre).

Otra ventaja respecto a las reservas individuales es que la gestión de la memoria se simplifica enormemente. No es lo mismo liberar la memoria con un único `delete[]` que tener que programar un bucle que gestione múltiples borrados... las posibilidades de dejarnos memoria sin liberar en este segundo caso son mayores.

Pero claro, no siempre se puede aprovechar esta característica (por ejemplo si cada objeto tiene un ciclo de vida propio o si la lista puede crecer en el tiempo... pero si esta solución es aplicable a un problema desde luego será más rápida que andar gestionando reservas individuales.

Por otro lado, que el tamaño de la reserva venga dado por una función o una expresión no es algo dificil de encontrar. Un buffer usado para compresión puede tener un tamaño cuyo valor se base en aplicar logaritmos al tamaño del texto plano...

> ¿Esto está dentro de aritmética de apuntadores?

No, no se podría considerar aritmética de punteros. Esta etiqueta podría ser aplicable si el programa hubiese hecho algo así:

```
p + 0 = 67;
p + 1 = 72;
p + 2 = 15;
p + 3 = 81;
p + 4 = 23;
```

Que es lo mismo que está haciendo ahora mismo pero aplicando aritmética de punteros. C++ da para escribir muchos libros...